# CSS3 box-sizing in Safari not working when using display: table

Tags: css

```
    header {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari */
    padding:10px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    height:80px;
    display:table;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

I am using the CSS code above and in both Chrome and Firefox this is giving the header a total width of 960px like desired however in my Safari 6.02 which should just support "box-sizing" without the need for a prefix but I put one in as a fallback anyway I am getting a total width of 980px which means it is sized upon the content-box. Could anyone tell me why its not working for me ?

Comment: What's your doctype declaration?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML> declaration of the HTML page ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>You are using `display: table` on your `header`. This seems to trigger some additional paddings. Adding `border-collapse: collapse` seems to fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yhwb/1/ (without: http://jsfiddle.net/7Yhwb/)</strike>

**Edit:** I think this is a bug in the WebKit version (536) Safari 6.0.2 is using. In an old Chrome 20, which uses also WebKit 536, the bug is also present.

In the more recent Chrome versions which use WebKit 537 it seems to be fixed.

To fix your problem I would switch to `display: block`.

Comment: Is this not the same as not having border padding in the first place though because agreed it creates the correct 960px width but at the expense of padding and borders which I require...

Comment: @HenryQuekett hups, sorry. you are absolutly right. It's getting late over here... Do you need the `display: table`? Changing to `display: block` works.

Comment: What I fail to understand is why in all other browsers through it is displaying at the correct 960px width due to the box sizing surly if display: table is adding some kind of hidden additional padding this would be standard for all browsers and doesn't answer the question why it just isn't working in safari ...